# toCharArray, Index out of bounds

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

Can somebody tell me why the .toCharArray() line is giving an Index Out of Bounds exception? And why is it even giving index 0 size 0 exception for a String? I haven't defined a String Array?!

Also, This code should run in O(n) time right?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class FirstNonRepeating {


public static List<Character> list = new ArrayList<Character>();
public static List<Character> list2 = new ArrayList<Character>();

public static String res(String x) {
    char[] y = x.toCharArray();

    for(char c:y){
        list2.add(c);
        if(list.contains(c)){
            list2.remove(c);
        }
        else{
            list2.add(c);
        }
    }

    if(list2.isEmpty()){
    return "NONE";
    }

    else return (""+list.get(0));

    }

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String a="Google";
    String z=res(a);
    System.out.println(z);
}

}
```

Comment: Are you sure that that's where the error lies? Because if it is, then it's a bug with the JRE (which is far and away not the correct conclusion).

Comment: FirstNonRepeating.res(String) line: 14 
  FirstNonRepeating.main(String[]) line: 40 
  x : IndexOutOfBoundsException  (id=16) 

line 40 is the assignment of z in the main method, So I guess the method res which was called might have given some error?

Comment: Where are you getting the exception? My guess is that it's in the line `else return (""+list.get(0));`. And please don't give line numbers unless you expect us to manually count the lines in the posted code.

Comment: I posted the error message in the comments!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your exception is here:

```
        if (list2.isEmpty()) {
            return "NONE";
        } else return ("" + list.get(0));
```

You check for emptiness `list2` and try to get first element from `list` which appears to be empty and exceptions is thrown. Change it to:

```
... else return ("" + list2.get(0));
```

Answer (score 1):

I see there are two list: `list` and `list2`. In the `for` loop you only added element `list2`, each element twice! So `list2` bocomes

> [G, G, o, o, o, o, g, g, l, l, e, e]

```
for(char c:y){
    list2.add(c); // added first time into list2
    if(list.contains(c)){ // false, as list is empty
        list2.remove(c); // never executed
    }
    else{
        list2.add(c); // added same char second time into list2
    }
}
```

Whereas `list` is still empty. Hence `list.get(0)` produced

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

in line,

```
else return (""+list.get(0));
```

> This code should run in O(n) time right?

Yes it is. The for loop will iterate up to input string `a.length` size.

Answer (score 0):

The Exception is not because of `.toCharArray()`. it is because of the condition you are checking `if(list.contains(c))`, as yu do not have any value in this `list` object. the exception is shown at the line `char[] y = x.toCharArray();` because it is the statement that was the last correctly executed line by the JRE.

Try initializing the `list` object before making any condition checks. I guess that will fix the issue.

Comment: `list.contains()` doesnt throw indexoutofbounds exception. Also the line is exception will be the line which threw the exception, not the one which was executed correctly.

Comment: no `list.contains()` will return false. see `JavaDocs`, error is at `list.get(0)`

Answer (score 0):

The Error is not on `.toCharArray()` method.

Its because your `list` is empty. Since your code never add any element to it.

Also you are checking for `list2` for empty condition.

```
if(list2.isEmpty())
```

But in `else` part, you are trying to fetch from `list` which is infact empty.

Hence the Error :  **Index Out of Bounds exception**

Answer (score 0):

Like the others have said above, the original problem was due to you trying to access an empty list. I think what you may want to try and do is rethink your solution to the problem, and you may avoid some of these pitfalls.

Your code could be simplified a little. I think you want something like this.

```
public class FirstNonRepeating {

    public static String res(String string) {

        char [] characters = string.toCharArray();
        boolean repeat = false;
        char last = characters[0];
        int length = characters.length; 

       for (int x  = 0; x < length - 1; x++){
          if(characters[x] != characters[x + 1]){

                if(x == 0) return Character.toString(characters[x]);

                if(characters[x] != last) return Character.toString(characters[x]);

            }

          last = characters[x];
       }

       return (last != characters[length - 1] ? Character.toString(characters[length - 1]) : "");
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String a = "Google";
        System.out.println(res(a));

        a = "oobgle";
        System.out.println(res(a));

        a = "oooooe";
        System.out.println(res(a));

    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, pretty much what I was going for, but the overall time for comparisons here will increase, no?

Comment: @codeninja I had a bug but it's fixed now. No this is O(n) since it's a linear search and may be literally faster due to less initialization and overhead.

Comment: @codeninja you should probably pick a correct answer.